# LDIF: Modify attr if exists; Add if not exists

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldif

Is there a way to do one of the following in an LDIF file?

- Ignore error (attr not found) when trying to delete an attribute

Or:

- If attribute exists, modify it
- If it doesn't exist, add it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to do this is simply using the *replace* action

```
dn: ...
changetype: modify
replace: attributeName
attributeName: xxx
```

Answer (score 4):

`ldapmodify` has a `-c` flag:

```
-c         continuous operation mode (do not stop on errors)
```

... which I guess should take care of your first point.

Comment: Oddly, using -c doesn't seem to do anything. According to the man page this is exactly what I want. Excellent answer... if it worked. I tested and confirmed ldapmodify works fine if I remove the delete: of the non-existent attribute and errors (16) with or without -c otherwise.

Comment: Solved: Problem was that it has to be done in completely separate *entries* in the LDIF -- one entry for the delete, then another separate entry for successive actions such as add.

Answer (score 1):

```
dn: ...
changetype: modify
add: attributeName
attributeName: xxx
-
delete: attributeName 
attributeName: value
-
delete: attributeOther
```

May also work for you. This allows multiple operations while listing the DN once.